# dropzone.js does not return the mimtype of .flv file on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dropzone.js, flv

Do anyone know why dropzone.js doesn't return mimtype of .flv file on chrome. Whereas on Mozila its working fine? Is there any way or fixes for this ? Here is the code that i am using.

```
    $("#dZUpload").dropzone({
                url: $('.upload-url').val(),
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                parallelUploads: 1,
                maxFiles: 1,
                maxFilesize:550,
                accept: function(file, done) {
                       alert(file.type);
                }
    });
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get `video/x-flv`. Chrome 47.0.2503.0 dev (64-bit), OS X.

Comment: I also made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Siguza/yektsn7p/) in case anyone wants to play around.

Comment: I just checked it on Version 45.0.2454.85 m (windows 7) and it not giving mim type for .flv.